# How to get the end time of AWS EBS volume snapshot ? I want to find out the time when the snapshot completed

Tags: amazon-web-services

> aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id $VOLUME_ID

output :

Found Services box: i-b657c36c

Found volume id: vol-ba131d5c

```
{
    "Description": ""
    "Encrypted": false,
    "VolumeId": "vol-ba131d5c",
    "State": "pending",
    "VolumeSize": 30,
    "Progress": "",
    "StartTime": "2016-01-21T13:48:34.000Z",
    "SnapshotId": "snap-cb1a238d",
    "OwnerId": "833371238208"
}
```

Found private IP address: 172.31.1.147

Comment: Why?  The snapshot contains the data as it existed on the volume at the beginning, not at the end.

Comment: Yep, but i need to know the end time because sometimes the snapshot takes hours so there should be a way to know when it completed and how long it took.

Comment: That's a reasonable requirement.  I wrote an automated overnight snapshotter, still using it, but haven't looked at it in a while... but I seem to remember this issue.  I think I solved it, after initiating the snapshots by polling the API in a sleepy loop until they were marked as complete and then tagging them with runtime or stop time, leaving the loop once there are no more snaps in "pending" status.  I'll try to dig up any notes from back then... I think that may be the only way.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it's been about 5 years, how you making out digging up those notes....